# subset sum find all subsets that add up to a number

Tags: java, sum, dynamic-programming, subset, subset-sum

I have been learning dynamic programming, and I want to take the classic subset sum problem a little further by printing out all the subsets which add up to a number.  How exactly would I go about doing this?  As of now, I know how to print true or false based on whether there is a subset that adds up to it

```
    public static boolean hasSum(int [] array, int sum)
{
    int len = array.length;
    boolean[][] table = new boolean[sum+1][len+1];

    int i;

    for( i = 0; i <= len; i++ )
        table[0][i] = true;

    for( i = 1; i <= sum; i++ )
        table[i][0] = false;

    for( i = 1; i <= sum; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 1; j <= len; j++ )
        {
            table[i][j] = table[i][j-1]; 

            if( !table[i][j] && i >= array[j-1] )
                table[i][j] = table[i-array[j-1]][j-1];
        }
    }        

    return table[sum][len];
}
```

if possible, I'd like to return an array of all of the subsets.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is harder than the original one.

For each `table[i][j]` which you set to `true`, you have to mark all its **predecessors** i.e. all the `table[i1][j1]=true`, due to which you marked `table[i][j]` as true. This way you build a kind of graph structure. 
The vertices of this graph are couples `(i,j)`.

Then when you want to print the answer, you have to trace back from `(i,j)` to all possible `(i1,j1)` and so on going backwards. For this, just an array won't be enough, you'll need additional/helper data structures.

Comment: yeah thats what I was thinking.  In each index of the table, would I then store the last number? So that to add up to say, 10 for {2,4,5,6,8,1), I could take the 1 as it was last to 10, then the 5 as it was last to 9 with the 4, and then the 4 from adding to 4, making it [4,5,1]?  I hope thats clear